Integrating calendly to create event in ruby and blocking google calendar
I want to integrate google calendar with calendly such that when I create an event it will block google calendar of the other users that are mentioned through API's. if possible in ROR
I have tried

Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService

and

Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event

But it is creating the event, but slots has not been blocked, even I have known sender. I am getting reminder before the event but the google calendar not getting blocked by default.
